# Xamarin C# For Android : Reading a Blob from SQLite

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I'm having a problem with reading from a particular column that has a Blob type.
The Blob is text and not a picture..

```
cursor.GetBlob  (cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow("data"))
```

returns "Blob 245"
OR if I put ".ToString()" at the end I get :
"System.byte[]"

It does not return the actual data

Can someone slap me across the face with the correct way of getting this blob data ...
As I'm sure it's something stupid that I'm missing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the Byte-Array: `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`. So this should work:

```
var data = cursor.GetBlob  (cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow("data"))
var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)
```

Hope this helps.